# Using ajax post to a https API in apache localhost

Tags: javascript, ajax, api

I'm trying to create a login page with bootstrap where on clicking the button an ajax call will be made to an API through "POST" which should send an OTP to my mobile.

I'm running this on apache localhost. On inspecting source I get the error

```
HTTP400: BAD REQUEST - The request could not be processed by the server due to invalid syntax.

(XHR)POST - https://<api>
```

and i dont receive any OTP

Ive tested the API on Postman and they work. I tried working around with the syntax but nothing worked.

```html
    <!--body>
    <form class="login100-form validate-form p-l-55 p-r-55 p-t-178" action="/Login_v8/otp.html">
     <span class="login100-form-title">Sign In</span>
     <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-16" data-validate="Please enter phone number">
      <input class="input100" type="phone" name="Ph" placeholder="Phone number" id="Ph">
      <span class="focus-input100"></span>
     </div>
     <div class="text-right p-t-13 p-b-23">
      <span class="txt1">Forgot</span>
      <a href="#" class="txt2">Username / Password?</a>
     </div>
     <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
      <button class="login100-form-btn" onclick="generate_otp()">Sign in</button>
     </div>
     <!-- other lines of code>
    </form>
    <!--other lines of code>
    <script>
     function generate_otp(){
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var Ph = document.getElementById('Ph');
      var arr = {Ph: "968*******",
       device:{
        deviceId: "1234"
        platform: "1",
        appType: "0"
       }
      };
      let json = JSON.stringify(arr);
      request.open("POST","<api>", false);
      request.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json');
      request.send(JSON.stringify(arr));
     }
    </script>
```

It should send an OTP to my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible the code below is malformed

```
    var arr = {
    Ph: "968*******",
    device: {
        deviceId: "1234"
        platform: "1",
        appType: "0"
    }
};
```

There is a comma missing

```
        ....
        deviceId: "1234",
        platform: "1",
        .....
```

Also, you have stringnified arr twice. Did you mean to send off this line

```
 let json = JSON.stringify(arr);
```